# Calculate the total number of country names in the queue that begins with the same letter

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stack, queue

I'm interested in how to count the number of names in a queue that begin with the same first character.

My program will be asking the user to input several names, and the names will be stored in a queue. However, I am required to count the number of names in the queue that begins with the same first character. How do I do that? I'm new to java so I don't know much.

> It should print the following statistics:
>   - The total number of country names in the queue that begins with the same letter.
>   - To compute the above statistics you may use other data structures, such as Array, or ArrayList/Vector.

Example:

> User inputs/what is in the queue:
>
> 1. Brazil
> 2. Italy
> 3. Singapore
> 4. Spain
> 5. Switzerland
> 6. Iceland

Output:

> Total number of countries start with I : 2
>
> Total number of countries start with S : 3

I've tried searching around on this but I haven't really found a solid method to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE: I am not allowed to use any of Java's mechanisms and have to implement it myself**

here's my program so far.

Comment: You said that you're able to use an ArrayList, so what's the point of the Queue class that you wrote? It looks like you're trying to write your own List class, but there's far easier methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to get count of countries that start with specific character-

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(!myQueue.isEmpty()) {
    myList.add((String)myQueue.dequeue());
}


TreeMap<Character, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    String country = myList.get(i);
    Character first = Character.toUpperCase(country.charAt(0));
    if(counts.get(first) == null) {
        counts.put(first, 0);
    }
    counts.put(first, counts.get(first) + 1);
}
//Now print the counts

TreeSet<Character> keySet = new TreeSet<Character>(counts.keySet());
Iterator<Character> iterator = keySet.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Character key = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Total number of countries start with " + key + " : " + counts.get(key));
}
```

**EDIT: Sample Code With Sample** *Queue* **Class**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Queue myQueue = new Queue(10);
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(!myQueue.isEmpty()) {
            myList.add((String)myQueue.dequeue());
        }       
        TreeMap<Character, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            String country = myList.get(i);
            Character first = Character.toUpperCase(country.charAt(0));
            if(counts.get(first) == null) {
                counts.put(first, 0);
            }
            counts.put(first, counts.get(first) + 1);
        }
        //Now print the counts
        TreeSet<Character> keySet = new TreeSet<Character>(counts.keySet());
        Iterator<Character> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Character key = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Total number of countries start with " + key + " : " + counts.get(key));
        }
    }
}

class Queue {
        String[] items;
        int pointer = 10;
    Queue(int size) {
        items = new String[10];
        items[0]="Austria";
        items[1]= "United States";
        items[2]="Nepal";
        items[3]="Bhutan";
        items[4]="China";
        items[5]="Brazil";
        items[6]="Africa";
        items[7]="Sri Lanka";
        items[8]="Italy"; 
        items[9]="India";
    }
    Object dequeue() {
        pointer--;
        return items[pointer];
    }
    boolean isEmpty() {
        return pointer == 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `String country = (String)myList.get(i);` ...so you think this works?

Comment: not exactly... I haven't studied about Maps so I don't quite understand what you're doing. Is there any other way besides the Maps method?

Comment: Maps are very easy structures which store data in key => value form. I have used TreeMap which actually stores the data in sorted fashion using keys. It will help you to output in sequence of first character in alphabetic order.

Comment: do you need further help?

Comment: String country = (String)myList.get(i); works fine because while adding to the queue you have actually passed String objects that were input from console.

Comment: I got it. You need to deque all items and add them to the myList. It will work. I have editted the answer.

Comment: *"works fine because while adding to the queue you have actually passed String objects that were input from console."* I guess you already notices, that this is very wrong. You can't cast `Queue` to `String`, just because `Queue` may refer to Strings in on of its fields.

Comment: @KamalSingh i've tried adding them into my program, however, it still won't work. The program stopped at `System.out.println("Statistics: ");`

Comment: You have removed the code of Queue class you created. So as sample I am sending you the dummy Queue class, please replace it with yours Queue class. I see that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use any Java collection, you can simply create int array of every possible character filled by zeros, then convert every first character of string in your queue to int, and increment this array index. Something like:

```
// on start of program
int[] charCounts = new int[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < charCounts.length; ++i)
{
    charCounts[i] = 0;
}

// your loop
System.out.println("List of countries visited: ");
for(int i=0; i<randNum; i++)
{
    System.out.print((i+1)+". ");
    if (!myQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        String s = (String)myQueue.dequeue();
        int charCode = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
        ++charCounts[charCode];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you are allowed to use an ArrayList and String, you could quite simply create an `ArrayList` of type `String`, have the user add the countries to the ArrayList, and then create a loop to iterate through the ArrayList and count the amount of times the character specified occurs at the start of each word.

Create the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm going to manually add some countries to the list, but in your case you'd have a user enter it:

```
    listOfCountries.add("Germany");
    listOfCountries.add("Scotland");
    listOfCountries.add("England");
    listOfCountries.add("Switzerland");
    listOfCountries.add("Uganda");
```

Then write a method to count.  You'd call the method `String.charAt()` to see if it matches the character you're looking for:

```
private int countStartingCharacters(ArrayList<String> countries, char match){

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++){
        if (countries.get(i).charAt(0) == match) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

I'd cast everything to lowercase in the count method just to be safe and add input validation but that's all.  Hope it helps.

Comment: How exactly can I call the method countStartingCharacters in the main driver program though? is it `listOfCountries.countStartingCharacters` ??

Comment: @Minchae Make it static and call it from your main method after the user enters the countries simply by writing: countStartingCharacters(countries, 'x').  'x' being the character you want to match with.  Make sure to assign it to a new variable and then print the statistics however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method inside the queue class that, given a letter, it returns the number of names in the queue that begins with that letter:

```
public int countriesWith(char c){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].startsWith(String.valueOf(c))){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: try this: if( ((String)items[i]).startsWith(String.valueOf(c)) ) , but if your queue will always be of String, is better to declare items as String[].

Comment: How would the method work at the main driver program though?

Comment: Take the char c from the input and then: System.out.println("Total number of countries start with " + c + " " +  myQueue.countriesWith(c) );

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in simple way.Try this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listNames = new ArrayList<>();
    listNames.add("Austria");
    listNames.add("Russia");
    listNames.add("Brasil");
    listNames.add("Argentina");
    listNames.add("Ukraine");
    listNames.add("Belarus");
    listNames.add("Litvia");
    listNames.add("Livia");
    listNames.add("Italia"); 

    Map<String, Integer> nameCount = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listNames.size(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < listNames.size(); j++) {
            if (listNames.get(i).substring(0, 1).equals(listNames.get(j).substring(0, 1))) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        nameCount.put(listNames.get(i).substring(0, 1), count);
     }
    // output
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> set : nameCount.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(set.getKey() + " : " + set.getValue());
    }

}
```